# torch.cuda.is_available returns false when using ssh remote debugging

Tags: python, pytorch, gpu

when I run these code directly on colab terminal or notebook:

```
import torch
print(torch.cuda.is_available())
```

it returns True.
but when I using ssh remote debugging to run this code:

```
sudo+ssh://root@122.27.154.150:1012/usr/bin/python3 -u /content/drive/MyDrive/python_projects/t.py
```

where  t.py contains code:

```
    import torch
    print(torch.cuda.is_available())
```

It always return False.

I also tried to run `python t.py` or `python2 t.py` directly on colab，it always returns True.But when I switch to ssh remote running, it returns False.

What is the problem? and how to fix it ?